# How to extract current page text & select them using pdfBOX?

Tags: android, pdf

I'm using PDFBOX to extract text from pdf. But problem is, it's not showing current page's text of pdf while using **pdfStripper.getCurrentPage();**. And while using **setStartPage & setEndPage**, it only shows compile time texts. And the major problem is, it's unable to select the extracted text.

Comment: Unfortunately you show no code. This makes understanding your problem very difficult (I actually have no idea what your code might be and which assumptions you have). Furthermore, what do you mean by *"select the extracted text"*?

Comment: PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
   pdfStripper.setStartPage(0);
   pdfStripper.setEndPage(1);
  
   parsedText = "  " + pdfStripper.getText(document);

Comment: "select the extracted text" means i would like to copy the extracted  text. 
and https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android this is github link...

Comment: `setStartPage` is 1-based. So your current code will only extract text from the first page. And what are "compile time texts" ?